# How do I map a codable JSON struct into Data for decoding a response?

Tags: swift

I am having trouble compiling the following code — it fails with “'Cannot convert value of type 'CheckUserNameAvailability' to closure result type 'JSONDecoder.Input' (aka 'Data')”.

How do I map the `CheckUserNameAvailability` JSON returned by the server to `Data`?

```swift
// This is the JSON returned by the server
// {
//    "Username" : "Foo1Bar2",
//    "Available" : true
// }
struct CheckUserNameAvailability: Codable {
    let Username: String
    let Available: Bool
}

enum tvAPI {
    static func checkUserName(username: String) -> AnyPublisher<CheckUserNameAvailability, Error> {
        // ...
    }
}

func testUserName() {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let me = "Foo1Bar2"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys
    cancellable = tvAPI.checkUserName(username: me)
        .map { $0 } // compilation fails with “Cannot convert value of type 'CheckUserNameAvailability' to closure result type 'JSONDecoder.Input' (aka 'Data')”
        .decode(type: [CheckUserNameAvailability].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        // .print()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {completion in
            print(completion)
        },
        receiveValue: { availability in
            print("\(availability)")
        })

    RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10))

    withExtendedLifetime(cancellable, {})
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that the title more accurately describes your question and removed unnecessary code that didn't demonstrate your problem. Please see [ask] and make sure to include a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`tvAPI.checkUserName(username:)` returns a publisher with output type `CheckUserNameAvailability`. The [`decode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/decode(type:decoder:)) method on the publisher requires that the publisher's output matches the decoder's input:

```swift
func decode<Item, Coder>(type: Item.Type, decoder: Coder) ->
    Publishers.Decode<Self, Item, Coder> where
      Item : Decodable,
      Coder : TopLevelDecoder,
      Self.Output == Coder.Input
```

However, `CheckUserNameAvailability` is not compatible with `JSONDecoder.Input` (aka `Data`).

You don't need to decode the data:

```swift
cancellable = tvAPI.checkUserName(username: me)
    // .print()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: { availability in
        print("\(availability)")
    })
```